# Is there a difference between "wear something to work" and "wear something at work"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Is there a difference between *wear something to work* and *wear something at work*? For example:

> The boss always wear a black suit **to**/**at** work.

If there is no real difference in meaning, then which one is more common?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clothes you wear ***to work*** are those you dress yourself in on a working day, like the boss's black suit.

Something you wear ***at work*** *could* mean a uniform you change into, or protective clothing you put on, when you get there.

Comment: Let's say I wear the same clothes at work as the close in which I go to work. Do I say "I wear a suit to work" or "I wear a suit at work"? Or there is  no real difference?

Comment: You could use either for a suit, but, as I explained, wearing something _at work_ could have a specific meaning.